# NgxWebstorageModule -> StrategyIndex No provider for StrategyIndex

Tags: angular, session, session-cookies, angular8, nativescript-angular

I have added ngx-webstorage to my angular8 nativescript project, In localhost it's working fine, But When I give production build with below command no error at all `ng build --prod --optimization=false --base-href /testit/"`

When I open in browser the page is not loading and in the console it shows the below error, any suggestion on how to resolve it.

**Uncaught NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgxWebstorageModule -> StrategyIndex]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgxWebstorageModule -> StrategyIndex]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for StrategyIndex!**

Comment: Same issue with me. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add `StrategyIndex`, `StrategyCacheService`, in your app module

```
import { NgxWebstorageModule, StrategyIndex, StrategyCacheService } from 'ngx-webstorage';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
       AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       BrowserAnimationsModule,
       AppRoutingModule,
       NgxWebstorageModule.forRoot({ prefix: 'prefix name here', separator: '-' }),
    ],
    providers: [
       StrategyIndex,
       StrategyCacheService,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```